# kotlin type inference failed when calling an inline function using reified return type in a string template

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

I have a an inline function which uses a reified output type like the following:

```
class Config {
    inline operator fun <reified T> get(v:String):T = ...
}
```

I'd like to call that function from a string template like the following:

```
val c = Config()
val v:String = "value of key is: ${c["key"]}"
```

When I attempt this, I get a compile warning saying the following:

```
Error:(26, 19) Kotlin: Type inference failed: Not enough information to 
infer parameter T in inline operator fun <reified T> get(v: String): T
Please specify it explicitly.
```

I am aware that that the following code works

```
val c = Config()
val s:String = c["key"]
val v:String = "value of key is: $s"
```

However, I would like to tell kotlin the proper type to use in a one-liner if possible.

Using a cast doesn't seem to work:

```
val v:String = "value of key is: ${c["key"] as String}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only thing that works in the current version (1.2.30) is to use the `get` method instead of brackets and to specify the type parameter explicitly:

```
val v = "value of key is: ${c.get<String>("key")}"
```

As far as I understand, the cast is supposed to work (starting with Kotlin 1.2, the compiler can infer expected types from casts), but in this specific case it doesn't work, which may be a bug, so you may want to file a YouTrack issue.

(It doesn't actually matter that the function is inline. The problem is that it returns T, and the T does not depend on parameter types, so it can be inferred only based on the type of the variable to which the value is assigned. In the case of a string template, there is no way to provide this information other than by specifying T explicitly.)